# "Show as expanded" in Drupal menu structure not working

Tags: drupal

In Drupal back-end (admin), I go to Structure > Menu > edit > checkbox "show as expanded" for all my links, and Saved Configuration, and the hierarchy doesn't show up when I look at my site. Why is this?

Comment: Some themes do not include the sub menus. What theme are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default drupal theme, I never changed it @2pha

Answer (score 0):

Bartik (Drupal 7 default theme) does not support drodown/expanded menu.
check this link:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8184/how-to-make-the-main-menu-expanded

edit:
You can implement it by overriding/implementing your own `$main_menu` variable for use in page.tpl.php (in a preprocess function).
Or you could implement `THEME_links__system_main_menu`.
Or you could just install a menu module such as [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that. So I changed it, in hopes that a different theme would have dropdown/expanded menu, and I checkmarked everything in my menu for "show as expanded" and looked at front-end, still nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you look at my page, http://student17.cas181s.com/project the "add content" link in the navigation bar on the left, for example, you'll see a popup of the children, but I want it in a hierarchy format...just shown on the left @2pha

Comment: I have a menu dropdown, with menu items that have children, I've already check-boxed the "show as expanded" for literally all my menu items. Visitors viewing my front-end cannot see this: http://oi61.tinypic.com/bf0r2c.jpg (only I can see this, in back-end, as admin). Why is this? I'm using Bartik 7.34 theme @2pha

Comment: anonymous users can not see the links if they do not have the proper permission. I can only "Add content -> Basic page" because I have the permission to create a basic page. But I can not see "Add content -> Blog entry" because anonymous users do not have permission to create blog entries.

Comment: Be very careful. Allowing anonymous users to create pages is not a good idea. If a bot sees the link on this page and then goes to your site, you could have a massive amount of pages created.

Comment: As I said, Bartik does not support dropdowns/subitems in the main menu. I have updated my answer to provide some options.